# ExtJS: Selector for all sub-views of a view

Tags: extjs, extjs4

**Setup:** So I have a controller that manages a hierarchy of views. I want my controller to be able to pickup on any events fired within this view hierarchy.

*app/view/myView.js*

```
Ext.define('app.view.myView', {
    ...
    alias: 'widget.myview',
    buttons: [{ 
         ...
         handler: function() {
             this.fireEvent('someEvent', this, args); // handler in controller
         },
         ...
    }]
});
```

*app/controller/myController.js*

```
Ext.define('app.controller.myController', {
    ...
    views: ['myView', ...],
    init: function() {
        this.control({
             'someSelector': {        // what does this selector need to be?
                  someEvent: //handle event
             },
             ...
        });
    }
});
```

What does `'someSelector'` need to be to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selectors work in a very similar manner to CSS selectors:

`myView *`

Any child element at any depth under `myView`.

Comment: I totally thought I tried that already. Guess I didn't lol. My bad. Thanks for your time though